# Primefaces 3.4 in-cell editable table marks inputtext-cell as red after failed validation

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using a in-cell editable datatable in PF 3.4 with Mojarra/Tomcat 7.0.29.

My problem is that I'm applying a validation on the inputtext which works great. The only issue I have is that after the validation fails, the cell is marked as red. Even if I close (i.e. click the cancel button) the editable-mode, it remains red next time I try to enter edit-mode. I need to have the red highlighting removed ***after*** I close the editable mode.

Its mostly a cosmetic issue as everything is working fine.

Any ideas?

So far, I've tried `setValid(true)` on the component in my validator but it does not seem to help much.

Comment: @Bhavik: please don't format non-code as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component what you need is [ResetInput](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf).

> Input components keep their local values at state when validation fails. ResetInput is used to clear the cached values from state so that components retrieve their values from the backing bean model instead.

Attach the reset input component to an action to reset another component state

```
<p:commandButton ....>
    <p:resetInput target="input1" />
</p:commandButton>
```

An alternative solution would be using [ResetInput](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/resetInput.jsf) from PrimeFaces Extensions which also support the `event` attribute. By this way you can directly connect your `rowEditCancel` with the `resetInput` like this:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"/>
<pe:resetInput event="rowEditCancel" for="input1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using pe:resetInput elsewhere and in another way. Didn't know it could be used in this context as well.