# Primefaces 3.4 in-cell editable table doesn't mark inputtext-cell as red after failed validation

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, primefaces

I'm trying a same approach as this [Primefaces 3.4 in-cell editable table marks inputtext-cell as red after failed validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045803/primefaces-3-4-in-cell-editable-table-marks-inputtext-cell-as-red-after-failed-v). My problem is I can't make the cell mark red after validation fail but he could. Only after I click cancel and then click edit again, the cell will be mark as red which is the same as him because the input have not been reset yet.

Here is what I have done:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" editable="true">  
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}" />  
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tableBean.onCancel}"  />  
    <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:125px">  
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{car.model}" required="true"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column>    
    <p:column headerText="Options">  
        <p:rowEditor />  
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>
```

Please tell me what goes wrong with above code. I want to contact him personally but I can't do that on this site.

Comment: javaMS - the owner of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045803/primefaces-3-4-in-cell-editable-table-marks-inputtext-cell-as-red-after-failed-v

Comment: I see, try PrimeFaces 3.5, things have changed in inline editing department as you can see from labs showcase.

Comment: I have tried primefaces 3.5 as you suggested but sadly it doesn't work as I want. In version 3.5, it marks red the entire row instead of just the input box.